# The code to merge adjacent cells using VBA isn't working anymore and I can't seem to find the problem

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the code, but can't seem to find out. It's working fine with the other sheets, but with this one it's always implying there's an error, and the structure's exactly the same.

The error "Application-defined or object-defined error" shows up at the **Do While** line of the code.

It's working on the 3rd row, but not on the 4th

Here's an image of the Sheet:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Thanks in advance

```
Sub BPS_MergeCells()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim ColumnsInRange As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    'Last Column Used
    LastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blast Pro Series").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Rows
    For r = 3 To 4
        'Columns
        For c = 1 To LastColumn
            Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blast Pro Series").Cells(r, c) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blast Pro Series").Cells(r, c + 1)
                ColumnsInRange = ColumnsInRange + 1
                c = c + 1
            Loop

            Set rng = Range(Cells(r, c - ColumnsInRange), Cells(r, c))
            rng.Select
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            Selection.Merge
            ColumnsInRange = 0
        Next c
    Next r
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know if this is the reason for your problem, but you use `c` and variable in the `for`-loop and within that loop, you are modifying it's value (in the inner `While`). You never should do this (and it is forbidden in nearly all programming languages). Plus, you are not checking if `c` exceeds  `LastColumn` in the `While`-loop.

Comment: You're right! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you are changing a variable that is used in `for` loop in another loop, and the variable may exceed last_column. Create a auxiliary variable for this end as follows:

```
Sub BPS_MergeCells()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim ColumnsInRange As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim c_aux As Long

    'Last Column Used
    LastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blast Pro Series").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Rows
    For r = 3 To 4
        'Columns
        For c = 1 To LastColumn
            c_aux = c
            Do While c_aux < LastColumn And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blast Pro Series").Cells(r, c_aux) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blast Pro Series").Cells(r, c_aux + 1)
                ColumnsInRange = ColumnsInRange + 1
                c_aux = c_aux + 1
            Loop

            Set rng = Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r, c_aux))
            rng.Select
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            Selection.Merge
            ColumnsInRange = 0
        Next c
    Next r
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! It worked, I hadn't thought about that, thanks guys!